# There isn't a GitHub Pages site here

Tags: github, github-pages

I tried to setup two repository github pages. Just wondering why one works and the other doesn't.

Works - https://ngaisteve1.github.io/calculator/
Doesn't Work - https://ngaisteve1.github.io/BlackJackJS/

Second question is, is it possible for my to deploy my html with Javascript in GitHub pages or is it GitHub pages is only deploy html page?

Comment: both seem to work for me...

Comment: Both work for me also. GitHub Pages might take a moment to deploy most recent changes.

Comment: Both work for me too. It's probably for the reason pointed by @eyevan.

Comment: Neither works for me now, although it's been a year, so maybe the OP took them down.

Comment: In case you're using a custom domain and react or anything else that fails to copy your CNAME record into your build, you need to do that manually: https://dev.to/brettcnelson/getting-create-react-app-to-work-with-custom-domains-on-github-user-project-pages-2hp2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Both links work now. GitHub Pages might take a moment to deploy your most recent changes.
2. You can host any static content, including client-side JavaScript (GitHub Pages will not run any code for you on its back end).

Comment: I tried to access my page, but unable. https://ngaisteve1.github.io/BlackJackJS/blackjack.html

Comment: @Steve have you pushed it into the repo? Because it isn't there: https://github.com/ngaisteve1/BlackJackJS/

Comment: ya. after i rename my file to index.html, i can view it now at https://ngaisteve1.github.io/BlackJackJS/index.html but some files not loaded successfully i think

Comment: @Steve yep, some things are missing. Hit F12 to open development console and check network tab. https://ngaisteve1.github.io/BlackJackJS/tingle.js -- it's not there, it is `js` subdirectory. Fix the paths in `index.html`?